# How to store csv file such that it can be read in frontend running on Python and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, tradingview-api

I am new to Stackoverflow and also to programming, apologies if my question is stupid.

I am trying to build a website on Flask python but want to integrate Tradingview charts.

For this, I created an HTML page to show Tradingview charts which includes Javascript, and using Flask(Python) to run the website.

I have created Flask app rendering HTML page, however, when rendering the template it shows an error for not being able to access the data.csv file. Data.csv is a file where I have kept the stock data to be displayed on the chart.

Flask Code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tvchart"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const getData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('static/js/data2.csv');
  const resp = await res.text();
  //   console.log(resp);
  const cdata = resp.split('\n').map((row) => {
    const [time1, time2, open, high, low, close] = row.split(',');
    return {
      time: new Date(`${time1}, ${time2}`).getTime() / 1000,
      open: open * 1,
      high: high * 1,
      low: low * 1,
      close: close * 1,
    };
  });
  return cdata;
  //   console.log(cdata);
};

// getData();

const displayChart = async () => {
  const chartProperties = {
    width: 1500,
    height: 600,
    timeScale: {
      timeVisible: true,
      secondsVisible: true,
    },
  };

  const domElement = document.getElementById('tvchart');
  const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(domElement, chartProperties);
  const candleseries = chart.addCandlestickSeries();
  const klinedata = await getData();
  candleseries.setData(klinedata);
};

displayChart();
```

Flask Error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "stockstarapp" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2022 14:42:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2022 14:42:37] "GET /data2.csv HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Is this the path to your file: 'static/js/data2.csv'  ? Or is it called Data.csv?

Comment: data2.csv is a file where stock data is kept. And 'static/js/data2.csv' is the location where I have stored this file.

Additionally, is there any folder that we have to create from where all the CSV files can be accessed? For example, the templates folder contains HTML pages.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: better use absolute path with `/` at the beginning `'/static/js/data2.csv'`

Comment: error shows `"GET /data2.csv HTTP/1.1" 404` so you try to read from `/data2.csv`, not from `/static/js/data2.csv` - so you use wrong path in code. maybe you run different code - with `fetch("/data2.csv")`